# Restrict browser exiting Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a little app that uses selenium and works with two Chrome browsers simultaneously. 
I was wondering if there is a way to restrict permission to close the browsers.

I mean I want a user to be able to ONLY close the program by using the GUI window but not turning off the browser.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Did you try anything? I would try writing a custom Chrome plugin that would try to take care of that, but Chrome plugins don't usually can't have this much power over the browser. You could also try injecting an `beforeunload`-event handling script to every page that would decline the request for browser exit.

Comment: Thank YOU for reply. Actually , what I have so far is just a `try catch` block that reopens browsers in case they were closed. It also gives a message that "one should not close the browsers this way" . I will research more on the `beforeunload` Thank you for advice